# Calculation for input with specific value

Tags: javascript, input, calculation

I have few input with calculation what I need now is, summing value from input E but only those where in input D is value 1, the same for value 2 but result must go to another input.

What I got: https://jsfiddle.net/55wb58o3/1/

I know have to edit:

```
var sumaTotal = function() {
    var suma = 0;
    $('input[id=ford]').each(function(k, els) {
        var value = Number($(els).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) suma += value;
    })
    $('#onetotal').val(suma);
}
```

I know I had to add `var fraction = els.find('input[id=fraction]').val();`

and check `if (fraction == 1)` but I don't know, how should it look like finally?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding "Summing value from input E" . Let's say we're looking at a row where D is 1, what should happen?

Comment: I make fiddle with how finnaly it should look like https://jsfiddle.net/ymeb4hqp/ maybe it help you undurstand.